Spring Get OIDC user information with seperate Frontend and Backend as an additional Auth Method
I have a spring boot application with a user database, where users can login with their username and password. Now i want to add Gitlab as my second OIDC provider. My frontend gets the authorization code from gitlab, which it then sends to the backend. How can i exchange the authorization code for an access token, to get an email and return a valid JWT token.
i would like to use the spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client library
the problem is i want to keep my existing auth flow and don't want to use the tokens which are provided by oidc.
class DefaultSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    fun defaultSecurityFilterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {

        http
            .csrf { csrfConfigurer -> csrfConfigurer
                .disable()
            }
            .sessionManagement { sessionManagementConfigurer -> sessionManagementConfigurer
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            }
//            .authorizeHttpRequests {
//                it.requestMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
//                it.requestMatchers("/actuator**", "/actuator/**").permitAll()
//            }
            .addFilterBefore(AuthorizationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter::class.java)

        return http.build()
    }
}


